# Insert a Woocomerce product in specific product category

Tags: plugins, wp-insert-post

I'm a bit new to Woocomerce plugin and have a problem.

I need to create products from code not from admin page. Probably I will insert them with `wp_insert_post( $product )`.

The problem is I don't know how to set the category for this product. I know it's name, not the ID (in fact I know ID but it can change). How can I add the product to that category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) fx

> From Codex:
>
> This function relates an object (post, link etc) to a term and taxonomy
>   type (tag, category, etc). Creates the term and taxonomy relationship
>   if it doesn't already exist.

```
wp_set_object_terms( 'id of product', 'term name', 'product_cat', true );
```